# How can I include product description in Magento order email?

Tags: orders, email-templates, ce-1.9.2.4

I'm pretty new to Magento, so I ask if anyone of you has ever tried to include the product description in the order transactional email.

Is there a way to do it? I've Magento CE 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a addition to Charlie answer so that other can help.

In Magento CE 1.9.2.4 its come up with **rwd** package with **default** theme so to make changes you have to locate.

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml
```

and add `<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>` wherever you want it.

if you are using any custom them then path will be as

```
app\design\frontend\<package_name>\<theme_name>\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml
```

making any changes in default file is not a good idea at all as it may get reverted if you upgrade magento version.

so always create your theme either in rwd package or under your package.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

```
app\design\frontend\default\<tempate-name>\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml
```

and this line where you want to print description

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
```

Done

Comment: Hi Charlie and thanks for the prompt answer! My backend structure is /public_html/app/design/frontend/template_package/template_name/template and there's no folder called "email". Where do I have to go then?

Comment: if you are using default magento **rwd**  then it will be  `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml` else   `app\design\frontend\<package_name>\<theme_name>\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml`

Comment: I'm using a custom theme, and in app/design/frontend/template_package/template_name/template there's no folder called "email". Should I create it or should I modify the file app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml ? Thanks to all!

Comment: modify `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtm` file and check it works or not. may your theme using base email templates. otherwise you need to search it properly in your custom theme folder

Comment: no don't make changes in default file. create that path in you them then make changes in that file.

Comment: right first to confirm if its using rwd file you can make changes in this file if its using it then revert your changes and make the same path in your theme. other wise you have to check with your theme. i think it can be identify by the email which you received.